# Resource does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add role to Azure AD user using Graph API.

I am forming the post request as specified in this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#AddDirectoryRoleMembers). But the operation is not succeeded. The returned error is as below.

Request 
URL: POST  https:// graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles/474732f7-ab9e-4eb5-8689-f5a078f5ed5b/$links/members?api-version=1.6

post data:
{
  "url": "https:// graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryObjects/63d144b6-e2f2-4a4a-b623-13debfcb0ff0"
}

Response Data:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Resource '474732f7-ab9e-4eb5-8689-f5a078f5ed5b' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."
        }
    }
}
```

The error message says that the requested resource is not found, but when I list all the available directory roles using [Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#GetDirectoryRoles), it lists that particular directory role, so that particular directory role is already activated and its available. I am not sure about the second part ('queried reference-property') of the error message. Even MSDN has no documentation regarding this error.

I tested the API with 3 tenants, in that it failed for 2 tenants and succeeded for 1 tenant.

The below is the partial data(I have copied the role which I am trying to add user) of the request made for listing all available directory roles.

Request URL: GET https: //graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1

Response: (partial)

```
{
    "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.DirectoryRole",
    "objectType": "Role",
    "objectId": "474732f7-ab9e-4eb5-8689-f5a078f5ed5b",
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "description": "Service Support Administrator has access to perform common support tasks.",
    "displayName": "Service Support Administrator",
    "isSystem": true,
    "roleDisabled": false,
    "roleTemplateId": "f023fd81-a637-4b56-95fd-791ac0226033"
},
```

If I try to fetch the above role alone using the provided API then I am getting the same error.

Request URL : GET https://  graph.windows.net/test.onmicrosoft.com/directoryRoles/474732f7-ab9e-4eb5-8689-f5a078f5ed5b?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1

Response:
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource '474732f7-ab9e-4eb5-8689-f5a078f5ed5b' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."}}

**Application Info:**

The Azure AD Application has "Access your organization's directory" access right and I am accessing the application using the Global Administrator account.

I have tried giving "Directory Read Write" permission to the application, but same error is happening.

Comment: It's easier to help if you include actual requests as well and the response from getting the roles

Comment: I suspect you may be mixing endpoints. You've tagged this question with both [microsoftgraph] and [azure-graph-api] which are different APIs. They use very similar URIs which can get a little confusing (graph.windows.net vs. graph.microsoft.com). If you could provide the URL you are using it would help with diagnosing what is going on here.

Comment: @GSM  @ Marc  I have added more info.

Comment: I think I am playing bad with application access rights. Please verify it.

Comment: Did you find a solution @RajanRaj? I've run into the same and don't have a clue what's wrong.

Comment: I've run into this error again today on a tenant and application that worked for months. Was surprised to see my own comment from Dec 6. I don't remember what solved the issue back then, and I don't have a clue what's wrong this time either. The same application still works fine against another tenant.

Comment: @EivindGussiåsLøkseth. I am not sure how did I solve this one. But our current code base has c# AzureActiveDirectory Client(Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient) code and it works fine.

Comment: @EivindGussiåsLøkseth Facing the same issue. Found any solution??

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni Try with Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient. It will work.

Comment: @RajanRaj: Thanks for reply. I am facing this issue on Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient itself.